# Add/update/delete products in json file using angular2 with http and observables

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular2-services

How can I Add/update/delete products/items in json file using angular2 with http and observables. Below is my code, GET Products is working fine. Please advise the others

**product-list.component**

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
pageTitle: string = 'Product List';
imageWidth: number = 50;
imageMargin: number = 2;
showImage: boolean = false;
listFilter: string;
errorMessage: string;

products: IProduct[];

constructor(private _productService: ProductService) {

}

toggleImage(): void {
    this.showImage = !this.showImage;
}

deleteItem() : void {
    this._productService.deleteProduct();
}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._productService.getProducts()
            .subscribe(products => this.products = products,
                       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

**product.service.ts**

```
export class ProductService {
private _productUrl = 'api/products/products.json';
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

constructor(private _http: Http) { }

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

deleteProduct(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
    let id : number = 1;        
    return this._http.delete(`${this._productUrl}/${id}`) 
                     .map((res:Response) => res.json()) 
                     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); 
}
```

**product-list.component.html**

```
<tbody>
                <tr *ngFor='let product of products | productFilter:listFilter'>
                    <td>
                        <img *ngIf='showImage'
                             [src]='product.imageUrl'
                             [title]='product.productName | uppercase'
                             [style.width.px]='imageWidth' 
                             [style.margin.px]='imageMargin'>
                    </td>
                    <td><a [routerLink]="['/product', product.productId]">
                        {{product.productName}}
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ product.productCode | lowercase }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.releaseDate }}</td>
                    <td>{{ product.price | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2' }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <ai-star [rating]='product.starRating'
                                (ratingClicked)='onRatingClicked($event)'>
                        </ai-star>
                   </td>
                   <td>
                       <button class="delete"(click)="delete(product); $event.stopPropagation()">X</button>
                   </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

**JSON file**

```
[
{
    "productId": 1,
    "productName": "Leaf Rake",
    "productCode": "GDN-0011",
    "releaseDate": "March 19, 2017",
    "description": "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle.",
    "price": 19.95,
    "starRating": 3.2,
    "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/26215/Anonymous_Leaf_Rake.png"
},
{
    "productId": 2,
    "productName": "Garden Cart",
    "productCode": "GDN-0023",
    "releaseDate": "March 18, 2017",
    "description": "15 gallon capacity rolling garden cart",
    "price": 32.99,
    "starRating": 4.2,
    "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/58471/garden_cart.png"
},
{
    "productId": 5,
    "productName": "Hammer",
    "productCode": "TBX-0048",
    "releaseDate": "May 21, 2017",
    "description": "Curved claw steel hammer",
    "price": 8.9,
    "starRating": 4.8,
    "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/73/rejon_Hammer.png"
},
{
    "productId": 8,
    "productName": "Saw",
    "productCode": "TBX-0022",
    "releaseDate": "May 15, 2017",
    "description": "15-inch steel blade hand saw",
    "price": 11.55,
    "starRating": 3.7,
    "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/27070/egore911_saw.png"
},
{
    "productId": 10,
    "productName": "Video Game Controller",
    "productCode": "GMG-0042",
    "releaseDate": "October 15, 2017",
    "description": "Standard two-button video game controller",
    "price": 35.95,
    "starRating": 4.6,
    "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/120337/xbox-controller_01.png"
}
```

]

Comment: an Observable won't do anything if you don't subscribe to it. `this._productService.deleteProduct().subscribe();` should work.

Comment: Claiming that code someone else wrote is yours is just.. sad: [Angular2-GettingStarted](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted)

Comment: seems to be a local file... if it truly is just a local file, you cannot do anything else than get request. You can't modify a file get post requests unfortunately...

Comment: @R.Richards Maybe I'm naive, but somehow I get the feeling that OP is not claiming that he has written the code which this is obviously based on, but rather just states that this is his code which he has a problem with. Do you get what I mean? If not, then unacceptable. Of course it should be definitely be stated that... *"this is my code, which is based on the following code..."* But as said, maybe I'm naive and belive this would be the case :P

Comment: @AJT_82 You could very well be right. I am sure there is no ill intent here. I took the PS course, so recognized the code immediately. So much of it is line-for-line the same. A disclaimer would be nice. Anyway, have a good one! :)

Comment: @R.Richards I never claimed anything above. It is just a practice code following with the Angular2-Getting Started Course by Deborah K, not an enterprise level application that can cause copy rights issue for you. So, relax and happy learning :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I replied to your question in the discussion Tab for this course. Here was my answer:

You cannot add, update, or delete rows from the product.json file using http. Only the get works.

To add, update, and delete data with http, you need a back-end server. There is an in memory back-end server you can use to try out the add, update, and delete without having to actually set up a back-end server.

For more information and sample code see: https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=angular-2-reactive-forms&author=deborah-kurata&name=angular-2-reactive-forms-m8&clip=0&mode=live

Comment: Thank you so much Deborah :)